# Kendo UI (Graph) Add relief to the bubbles on the Bubble chart

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, styles, bubble-chart

I was wondering if it's possible to add a relief to the bubbles on the Kendo UI Bubble charts, because, with the 15 given themes, all bubbles stay flat :
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bubble-charts/index

It would be nice to add a 3D-style like the pie chart (Uniform style):
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/index

I guess it could be done by adding a CSS to the SVG, but I'm kind of lost.

Any ideas ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found a solution. You have to call this code after every refresh or draw call :

```js
var svg = $('svg');
var circles = svg.find('circle');
var svgEl = svg[0];

$.each(circles, function (key, circle) {
  var fillColor = $(this).attr('fill');
  var id = fillColor.replace('#', 'kgrad');
  var stops = [
    {offset: '0', 'stop-color': fillColor, 'stop-opacity': 0.3},
    {offset: '0.84', 'stop-color': fillColor, 'stop-opacity': 0.95},
    {offset: '0.85', 'stop-color': fillColor, 'stop-opacity': 0.7},
    {offset: '0.99', 'stop-color': fillColor, 'stop-opacity': 1}];
  if (svg.find('#' + id).length === 0) {
    var svgNS = svgEl.namespaceURI;
    var grad = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'radialGradient');
    grad.setAttribute('id', id);
    for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
      var attrs = stops[i];
      var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'stop');
      for (var attr in attrs) {
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr))
          stop.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
      }
      grad.appendChild(stop);
    }
    var defs = svgEl.querySelector('defs') || svgEl.insertBefore(document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'defs'), svgEl.firstChild);
    defs.appendChild(grad);
  }
  $(this).attr('fill', 'url(#' + id + ')');

}, this);
```